# how to implement delete and reschedule local notification based on uiswitch ON/OFF case in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am displaying all user scheduling local notifications in a tableview. In the tableview I am using `UISwitches`. If the user sets switch OFF in particular index in tableview then that local notification should not fire (Here, I cancel the notification). My question is how to reschedule the particular local notification?

Comment: What is your exact problem?  You would reschedule the notification the same way you scheduled it in the first place.

Comment: not in first place ,that notification same index in tableview

Comment: You should set a tag to for each switch and unique id for each notification.

Comment: in switch is in OFF state  the  background and terminate states the local notification is should be not come, but notification is coming

Comment: You cancel the notification from NSNotification Array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in which you can switch off the particulat notification on basis of unique id

```
  for(UILocalNotification *notification in notificationArray)
                {



              NSLog(@"%@",[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"alarmUiqueId"]);
                NSLog(@"%@",alrm.uniqueId);
                if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"alarmUiqueId" ] isEqualToNumber: alrm.uniqueId])
                {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification ] ;
                }
            }
```

Comment: if that particular notification switch off to switch on ( how to reschedule that particular notification )

Comment: You have a unique id of that particular notification so reschedule  that notification as you required. @himagiri

Comment: use core data or SQLite to save the record of the notification @himagiri

Comment: i am saved in coredata but retrive to assign the same record to local notification(rescheduled) in switch case

Comment: The code you write to schedule the notification just use this code again but now time and date is change @himagiri

Comment: same time with repeated time interval in that particular notification for selected days

Comment: I didn't understand , You want to reschedule the notification when the user switch on?? The time and date is selected by user?

Comment: Than you have to also save the date and time string into core data

Comment: You have to make one complete object for one notification and the object contains time, id, or whatever you want so  its easy to use wherever you want